# BodyTagSupport and jsp:forward with static resource

Tags: java, jsp, taglib

I have many JSPs with scriptlets so I need to use BodyTagSupport.

The problem is that inside the tag there is `<jsp:forward ..>` to a .htm page and I get this:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been
>   called for this response.

If I use a jsp everything is fine.

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

(I use Apache Tomcat as a server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a Tomcat bug. It should be fixed from Tomcat 7.0.30 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

the tag redirects the request to another jsp or servlet and your jsp can't write anything else.
after the tag, your jsp must return.